# Generating post-synthesis verilog model in Quartus II

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga

I have Xilinx background and now I happened to write some code on Altera devices. I have a question about generating post-synthesis models (also post-fit). On Xilinx I had `netget` which was able to generate verilog or vhdl post-synthesis model of my design which I was able to use freely for example in iverilog compiler. I quartus ii i have found `quartus_eda` tool but I am not able to perform what I wanted, I can generate `*.vo` files which looks fine but I am not able to find libraries to cover elements used there. I am using `--tool=modelsim`. Where I should look after them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [ModelSim-Altera Precompiled Libraries](http://quartushelp.altera.com/current/mergedProjects/eda/simulation/modelsim/eda_ref_msim_precomp_lib.htm) for pre-compiles libraries for Altera devices in ModelSim simulation.

The [Preparing for EDA Simulation](http://quartushelp.altera.com/current/master.htm#mergedProjects/eda/eda_topics/quartus2/eda_pro_advanced_options.htm) may also be helpful.

However, you may re-consider doing post-synthesis/fit simulation, since functional simulation at RTL level combined with Static Timing Analysis (STA) maybe an alternative approach.  If the intention is to verify timing with post-fit simulation, then note that Altera apparently is abandoning this support for this, since timing information in Standard Delay Format Output File (.sdo) files is not generated for post-fit simulation information for e.g. Cyclone V devices.

Comment: What I was looking for was `quartus/eda/sim_lib` which should do the job for now. I found this thanks to link you provided so I mark this as solution. I do not understand why I could not find this directory before. I understand STA, but for now I need to make sure that synthesis and fitting process generate results as I expect so I needed primitives simulation models.

Comment: If the purpose is to check that the generated netlist matches the source RTL, then an equivalence checker will do a thorough job, and you can avoid writing a test bench for stimuli.